# How do you search for a & (ampersand) in the tsql contains function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, full-text-search

I have a table T which has a column C which contains text that have the character & within it, but if I do the following query, it returns nothing, although I may have 10 rows.

```
SELECT * FROM T WHERE Contains(C, 'a&b')
```

Comment: you say you're looking for & but then you look for a&b

Comment: What I meant was that I am looking for the string a&b in this case, but for some reason, having the & character makes contain return nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use double quotes to make it a search term:

```
SELECT *
FROM T
WHERE CONTAINS(C, '"a&b"')
```

Otherwise you are searching for something that has a AND b.

Comment: This will require a full-text index of C

Answer (score 3):

Use like instead:

```
SELECT * FROM T WHERE C like '%&%'
```

if you're looking just for &

or

```
SELECT * FROM T WHERE C like '%a&b%'
```

if you need to search for a&b

Answer (score 1):

Could you use a LIKE instead of contains?

```
SELECT * FROM T WHERE C LIKE '%a&b%'
```

Answer (score 1):

What I do is create a copy of the column that replaces & and other non-alphanumeric characters with _. Then I can do this.

```
SELECT * FROM T WHERE Contains(C_searchable, 'a_b')
```

Comment: So Contains does not change the & to _ automatically?

Comment: No, it treats the & as word breaker. It treats "a&b" the same as "a b"