# Escaping an ampersand in SQL Server Full-Text Search query using CONTAINSTABLE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, escaping, full-text-search

I have a very peculiar case. My ASP.NET page calls a stored procedure of ours that performs a Full-Text Search query on our database. Some of the commonly searched strings include an ampersand because a few brands of our products (well-known brands, too) have an `&` in their name.

It turns out that in a certain case I get no results *unless I escape the ampersand* (`\&`), and in a certain other case I get no results *only if I escape the ampersand*.

I don't know if this is relevant, but (without giving out the brand names) one ends in `&b` and the other one in `&c`.

Is it possible that these strings (`&b` or `&c`) have some special meaning of their own? And that by escaping them I'm actually passing a special string to T-SQL?

**EDIT**

Additional info: after further testing, I proved that the error is in the stored procedure itself. Calling it with `&` or `\&` yields different results.

I'll try to post selected parts of the stored procedures. I won't post it all, because most of it isn't really relevant.

The `vParamBuca` parameter is the one that causes the troubles. Values could be `'word&letter'` or `word\&letter`.

```
SET @ricercaA = '''FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL,"' +
    REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(@vParamBuca)),' ', '") AND FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL,"') + '")'''
```

The variable `@ricercaA` is then used to create the query string:

```
[...]
FROM Products AS FT_TBL
LEFT OUTER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE (Products, Sign1, '+ @ricercaA + ') AS ColSign1_0 ON FT_TBL.ID = ColSign1_0.[KEY]
LEFT OUTER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE (Products, ManufacturerAdditionalText, '+ @ricercaA + ') AS ColManufacturerAdditionalText_0 ON FT_TBL.ID = ColManufacturerAdditionalText_0.[KEY]
LEFT OUTER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE (Products, ManufacturerForSearch, '+ @ricercaA + ') AS ColManufacturer_0 ON FT_TBL.ID = ColManufacturer_0.[KEY]
LEFT OUTER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE (Products, TuttaLaRiga, '+ @ricercaA + ') AS ColTuttaLaRiga_0 ON FT_TBL.ID = ColTuttaLaRiga_0.[KEY]
[...]
```

**EDIT 2**

Many thanks to @srutzky for pointing me in the right direction! In the meanwhile, I also found a data inconsistency where one of the brands with the `&` in its name was modified not to have the `&`, and the other one wasn't modified (bottom line, my current problem is caused by that: a partial fix that was made by someone in the past).

Anyway, back on track. Now I understand that the `&` character in the `CONTAINSTABLE` function is treated as a logical AND (non bitwise).

I still need a solution for that. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714980/how-do-you-search-for-a-ampersand-in-the-tsql-contains-function) gives a solution that doesn't work for me (the conditions are not the same as mine). How could I perform a `CONTAINSTABLE` search for a string with an ampersand in it? Preferably without having to transform the ampersand to another safe character?

Comment: Not sure if it has anything to do with your problem but, & is the bitwise and operator in T-SQL.

Comment: ...and your .NET code. If you are passing the strings as strongly-typed parameters, an ampersand shouldn't cause any problems anywhere.

Comment: Escaping or not, `&` used to be a special character and the variations that you're seeing are probably related not to it being "escaped", but to what else is seen/searched AFTER SQL server takes `&` for what it means. Google it.

Comment: When you say "_performs a full text search on our database_", do you mean that you are using the actual Full Text Search feature, or a `LIKE '%' + @variable + '%'` operator? The `\` isn't a T-SQL escape, so if you aren't using Full Text Search (where `&` should also work as a logical `AND` when using the `CONTAINS` function), then perhaps your app code is translating `&` when not escaped with `\`.

Comment: Thank you all, I've posted the relevant parts of the T-SQL procedure. I'm afraid it has to do with the bitwise and though :(

Comment: @Simone Thanks for adding the code to the question. Why do you think it has anything to do with bitwise operations? The ampersand is in a string so it can't be a bitwise operation. You code proves that my suggestion is correct: the `&` is treated as a logical AND in the `CONTAINS` and `CONTAINSTABLE` functions. I will post an answer with that info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The odd behavior you are seeing is most likely due to the [CONTAINS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx) and [CONTAINSTABLE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189760.aspx) functions (both used with SQL Server's Full Text Search feature) using the ampersand ( `&` ) character as equivalent to the `AND` operator. The following statement is taken from the documentation for `CONTAINS`:

> The ampersand symbol (&) may be used instead of the AND keyword to represent the AND operator.

There is no mention of there being any escape character for it (and a back-slash isn't typically an escape character in SQL anyway).

---

**UPDATE**

Based on the information now provided in "Edit 2" of the Question, and additional research, I would say that you do *not* need to escape anything. It seems that putting the search phrases in double-quotes (as a result of using `FORMSOF`) treats the `&` as either a literal or a word-breaker, depending on the values on both sides of the `&`. Try the following examples:

```
DECLARE @Term NVARCHAR(100);

SET @Term = N'bob&sally'; -- 48 rows
--SET @Term = N'bob\&sally'; -- 48 rows
--SET @Term = N'r&f'; -- 4 rows
--SET @Term = N'r\&f'; -- 24 rows

SET @Term = N'FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL,"' + @Term + '")';

SELECT * FROM sys.dm_fts_parser(@Term, 1033, 0, 0);
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_fts_parser(@Term, 1033, 0, 1);
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_fts_parser(@Term, 1033, NULL, 0);
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_fts_parser(@Term, 1033, NULL, 1);
```

The results for `bob&sally` and `bob\&sally` are the same, and in both cases `bob` and `sally` are separated and never combined into a single exact-match string.

The results between `r&f` and `r\&f`, however, are not the same. `r&f` is only ever treated as a single, exact-match string because `r` and `f` alone are not known words. On the other hand, adding in the back-slash separates the two letter since `\` is a word-breaker, in which case you get both `r` and `f`.

Given that you stated in the Update that you have "*data inconsistency, where one of the brands with the "&" in its name was modified not to have the "&", and the other one wasn't*", I suspect that when you do *not* add in the `\` character you get the brand that was *not* modified (since it is an exact match for the full term). But when you *do* add in the `\` character, then you get the brand that *was* modified to have the `&` removed, since you are now searching on both pieces, each one matching part of that brand name.

I would fix the data to be consistent: update the brand names that had the `&` removed to put the ampersands back in. Then when people search using `&` *without* the extra `\` added, it will be an exact match. This behavior will be consisted across the data, and will not require you adding code to circumvent the natural operation of FTS, which seems to be an error-prone approach.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried a couple of experiments and now I understand what the AND operator does. However, I still need a solution: is it possible to somehow "escape" the ampersand? It would be better if I hadn't to transform it to some safe character.

Comment: Your answer is great and really helpful! I have just one more question: why doesn't `'r\&f'` return also the `r&f` record that is returned by `'r&f'`?

Comment: @Simone Not sure, exactly, as to why that is, and it might depend on your settings that are reflected in parameters 3 and 4 in the `sys.dm_fts_parser` TVF. I suspect that since `r\&f` breaks into both `r` and `f`, neither of them match `r&f` which is considered a single entity.